# $R^kp_{2,*} (p_1^* V\otimes P) =0$ for $k\neq g$ and $V$ is $\pi_*$ acyclic on abelian schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi: A\rightarrow S$ be an abelian scheme of relative dimension $g$, and $A^\vee$ its dual, and $P$ the Poincare bundle. We have the projections $p_1,p_2$ from $A\times A^\vee$ to $A$ and $A^\vee$. Suppose $V$ is $\pi_*$ acyclic. I want to ask if it is true that $R^kp_{2,*}(p_1^* V\otimes P) =0$ for $k \neq g$?

Comment: Can you give some motivation for this problem? It'd be more interesting to work on if we knew why we care.

Comment: It was from a paper I am reading about application of Riemann Roch theorem to abelian scheme, and the Poincare bundle.